# Rails 4: tell simple_form to use input type "date" instead of showing different select boxes like Rails 4's f.date_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

When I use Simple Form it shows three different select boxes for column type `date`. Instead of this I want Simple Form to show date attributes as HTML5 does. Specifically I want Simple Form to do the following:

```
<input type="date" name="org[established_at]" id="org_established_at">
```

For this I tried:

```
<%= f.input :established_at, as: :date %>
```

But this produces three different select boxes for date picking.

How do I tell Simple Form and Rails 4 to use input type "date"?

Comment: Same problem here, any luck with it?

Comment: Still hoping for the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I've done it like this:

```
f.input :established_at, as: :string, input_html: { class: :datepicker }
```

and used http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ to show the calendar

Answer (score 0):

In  my project I used next:

```
  = f.input_field :year, as: :datepicker, class: "string form-control teacher_kpk_year", readonly: true
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

applications.js

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field defined as date, you only need add the parameter html5 like this:

```
f.input :established_at, html5: true
```

But, if you haven't defined your field like date or something like that, you only need to add the alias to the previous declaration, like this form:

```
f.input :established_at, as: :date, html5: true
```

And both forms will render a date or datetime picker like bootstrap-datepicker

best regards,